# How to create expected object like tree

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an output object using the below object

```
[{
  "department_name": "Education",
  "sub_department_name": [{
    "name": "E1",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app1",
      "date": "2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "E2",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app2",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:02.109Z"
    }, {
      "name": "app3",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:50.012Z"
    }]
  }]
}];
```

The final output should look like this

```
[
  {
    "label": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Education",
        "collapsed": true,
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "E1",
            "collapsed": true,
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "app1",
                "collapsed": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "E2",
            "collapsed": true,
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "app2",
                "collapsed": true
              },
              {
                "label": "app3",
                "collapsed": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried using JavaScript method, but not able to achieve the expected output. Any help on this will be really helpful.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mpq2tazt/10/)

As requested, posting my code here

```
var obj = [{
  "department_name": "Education",
  "sub_department_name": [{
    "name": "E1",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app1",
      "date": "2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "E2",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app2",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:02.109Z"
    }, {
      "name": "app3",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:50.012Z"
    }]
  }]
}];
var deptObj = {};
var subMainObj = {};

var subChildrenArr = [];

var applnArr = [];
for (x in obj) {
  deptObj.label = obj[x].department_name;
  for (y in obj[x].sub_department_name) {
    var subDeptObj = {};
    subDeptObj.label = obj[x].sub_department_name[y].name;
    subChildrenArr.push(subDeptObj);
    for (z in obj[x].sub_department_name[y].app) {
      var applnObj = {};
      applnObj.label = obj[x].sub_department_name[y].app[z].name;
      applnArr.push(applnObj);
      subDeptObj.children = applnArr;

    }

  }
}

deptObj.children = subChildrenArr;
var deptArr = deptObj;
var root = {};
root.label = "root";
root.children = deptArr;
alert(JSON.stringify(root));
```

Comment: What is JavaScript old style? \m/

Comment: post the code here

Comment: @void using conventional method

Comment: you first need to normalize your input json.

Comment: Ok - so you have a result. What is the difference between that and what you want? See... if you explain what the problem is, then no-one's time is wasted, and confusion is avoided. Also... there is no `jQuery` anywhere in your code, so you should probably remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map`

```js
let json = [{
  "department_name": "Education",
  "sub_department_name": [{
    "name": "E1",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app1",
      "date": "2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "E2",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app2",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:02.109Z"
    }, {
      "name": "app3",
      "date": "2018-02-13T06:38:50.012Z"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "department_name": "Test",
  "sub_department_name": [{
    "name": "T1",
    "app": [{
      "name": "app1",
      "date": "2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"
    }]
  }]
}];

//Contruct the children
let children = json.map(o => {
  let child = o.sub_department_name.map(v => {
    let c = v.app.map(x => { return { "label": x.name, "collapsed": true }});
    return {
      "label": v.name,
      "collapsed": true,
      "children": c
    }
  });

  return {
    "label": o.department_name,
    "collapsed": true,
    "children": child
  };
});

//Contruct the final array
let result = [{
  "label": "root",
  "children": children
}];

console.log(result);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Your approach is not working if the input json is [{"department_name":"Education","sub_department_name":[{"name":"E1","app":[{"name":"app1","date":"2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"}]},{"name":"E2","app":[{"name":"app2","date":"2018-02-13T06:38:02.109Z"},{"name":"app3","date":"2018-02-13T06:38:50.012Z"}]}]},{"department_name":"Test","sub_department_name":[{"name":"T1","app":[{"name":"app1","date":"2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"}]}]}]

Comment: @user4324324 I used https://text-compare.com/ to compare my output to your desired output and it is identical.

Comment: You can test my output by clicking on `Run Code Snippet` button.

Comment: That's right! But as you see my input object is array object. If I pass another object in the input, the final outcome is with one object only. Just try with the let json=[{"department_name":"Education","sub_department_name":[{"name":"E1","app":[{"name":"app1","date":"2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"}]},{"name":"E2","app":[{"name":"app2","date":"2018-02-13T06:38:02.109Z"},{"name":"app3","date":"2018-02-13T06:38:50.012Z"}]}]},{"department_name":"Test","sub_department_name":[{"name":"T1","app":[{"name":"app1","date":"2018-02-06T18:30:00.000Z"}]}]}]

Comment: Ohh.. So You mean.. There are multiple objects.. Ill update my code

Comment: Yes since you have used json[0].sub_department_name, it takes only first object in the array. If you pass the input json which I hav given in my previous comment, You should get the output as [{"label":"root","children":[{"label":"Education","collapsed":true,"children":[{"label":"E1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"label":"app1","collapsed":true}]},{"label":"E2","collapsed":true,"children":[{"label":"app2","collapsed":true},{"label":"app3","collapsed":true}]}]},{"label":"Test","collapsed":true,"children":[{"label":"T1","collapsed":true,"children":[{"label":"app1","collapsed":true}]}]}]}]

Comment: I updated my code. I added a new layer of `.map` Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Awesome. This what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help. @user4324324